# MySQL is waiting why can I log in from the command line?

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

On Ubuntu 12.04, I run sudo service mysql stop. It responds mysql stop/waiting.

But then I can still log in to mysql from the command line. How is this possible?

Comment: service mysql stop<br>
[ ok ] Stopping MySQL database server: mysqld.

Comment: Does the above message appeared?

Comment: No, the output from the system is:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
service mysql stop
[ ok ] Stopping MySQL database server: mysqld.
```

If your server has stopped this message would have appeared. Since it didn't it means that MySQL is still running and that is why you could have still logged in. You can try the more brutal method

```
ps -C mysqld -o pid=
//You will get a pid, which is the process identification number, say it is 8082 then
kill -9 8082
```

PS: Please do note replace `8082` with the pid you see in the screen

Comment: I killed the process and restarted it with sudo service mysql start and everything works fine.